# Kendo-grid with clickable link

Tags: javascript, java, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am very new to angular etc. This is probably super easy for some but I am having trouble.

I have a kendo-grid with a few columns and would like to have one column  which will have a clickable link (ex. users) that will route the user to a new page which will take them to the (user section).

My question is what steps do I take for 
1. Create clickable link
2. Route the user to a new page and the specific section on that page that deals with (ex. users)

Comment: Are you trying to have the user select a user or have the user create a new user?  I recommend looking through this for all the functionality of the Kendo Grid https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/

Comment: I want the user to select the hyperlink and then get routed to a page where they can update etc.

Comment: I believe you are able to make a custom link, I use MVC so I am not familiar with Angular. I would submit a question to Telerik and ask them to walk you through creating a custom angular link for that.  They hopefully will give you a detailed explanation of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Which kendo are you using?

For Kendo Angular use kendo-grid-column

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
        <kendo-grid-column title="Name" width="40">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <a class="text-primary" [routerLink]="...">{{dataItem.name}}</a>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

For Kendo UI use grid options columns template

```
    columns: [
       {
            field: "name",
            title: "Name",
            template: "<a href href='...'>#:name#</a>",
            width: "250px"
        } as kendo.ui.GridColumn
    ],
```